# angular ui-router- ajax call on load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We are developing an single page application using angular JS and I am using state provider for configuring routes. Basically there is a global navigation view and a dashboard view. I have to pass few params from navigation to make a service call and then display the dashboard accordingly.I have split the states as two, one for navigation and other for dashboard. THe thing which i am not able to figure out is that where should i make ajax call to fetch dashboard data. Should i make it in navigation itself and pass it through resolve. or should i just pass the data to dashboard controller and make ajax call from there.  Below is my state

```
$stateProvider
 .state('home', {
     url: '/',
     templateUrl: 'templates/home.htm',
     controller: 'homeController',
 })
 .state('dashboard', {
     url: 'contact',
     templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.htm',
     controller: 'dashboardController'
 })
 .state('state3', {
     url: '/articles',
     templateUrl: 'templates/state3.htm',
     controller: 'state3Controller'
 });
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Comment: i think it will be better to pass the prams through URL,and use `resolve` @ state dashboard to call api you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This entirely depends on how you want the user experience to play out.

If you want to do all the data fetching *before* transitioning to the dashboard state, use a `resolve` state configuration

```
.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/contact',
    templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.htm',
    controller: 'dashboardController',
    resolve: {
        someData: function($http) {
            return $http.get('something').then(res => res.data);
        }
    }
}
```

then your controller can be injected with `someData`, eg

```
.controller('dashboardController', function($scope, someData) { ... })
```

This will cause the state transition to wait until the `someName` promise has been resolved meaning the data is available right away in the controller.

---

If however you want to immediately transition to the dashboard state (and maybe show a loading message, spinner, etc), you would move the data fetching to the controller

```
.controller('dashboardController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loading = true; // just an example
    $http.get('something').then(res => {
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.data = res.data;
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you Phil. I have used the second approach and it is working fine.